# Java Script Logical Operator In IF ELSEIF Statement

Tags: javascript

I have a problem here my code for elseif statement isn't working. How do I use the && operator in html or javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><font color = "blue" size = 23> Compute Letter Grade</font></p>
<br><br>


 <label for="numericgrade"><font size = 5>Enter Numeric Grade<font></label> &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp     <input type="text" id="txtgrade" style="width:30px"></input><br> <br><br>


<button onclick="myFunction()" style="height:50px; width:400px">compute letter grade</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("txtgrade").value >= 90) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Letter Grade is 'A'";
    } else if (document.getElementById("txtgrade").value >= 80 && document.getElementById("txtgrade").value < 90) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Letter Grade is 'B'";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "isn't working" ***how***?

Comment: For a start, you have a syntax error. The console in your web browser should be telling you you have a missing `}`.

Comment: The usage of `&&` is correct in your code.

Comment: BTW: instead of doing this three times: `document.getElementById("txtgrade").value` just do it once and store the value in a variable, then test that variable in your `if / else if`

Comment: And finally: There's no need for the `&& ... < 90` check, as you already have an earlier `if (... >= 90)` check and you're using an `else`.

Comment: the second part of the else if is not needed as it has to be less than 90 if it gets to this point because you check if it is greater than or equal to in the first

Comment: Other than the missing brace pointed out by @T.J.Crowder, logically this [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/0t9a1ka2/).  There are a number of improvements that can be made as noted in the other comments though.

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run. @thinker: When you ask for help, *stick around for a few minutes* so you can address questions/comments from people trying to help you.

Comment: thanks for the tips guys it's working now sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your script like this. Since you are checking the grade for greater than 80 in the else part, you need not to use && operator. Also your braces were missing.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var grade=document.getElementById("txtgrade");
        if (grade.value >= 90) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Letter Grade is 'A'";
        } else if (grade.value >= 80) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Letter Grade is 'B'";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `&&`. Your function is missing the closing brace.

You can use the console provided with Firefox or Chrome to find errors in your code.

Comment: ...and pretty much every other browser too.

Comment: Indeed! The bottom line is "use the console".